# How can I run multiple Windows phone 8.1 emulators concurrently?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-8-emulator, windows-phone-8-sdk, windows-phone-emulator

I'm trying to load test a Windows phone app and ideally need to have about 20 instances of the Windows phone 8.1 emulator running at the same time. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to have one WP emulator run multiple instances but you can run multiple different WP emulators (VGA, WVGA, if you also include the WM10 emulators for multiple SDK version you may come up to 20).

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into that.